# How to match pattern 2.0.0.XXX in lua?

Tags: lua, pattern-matching, string-matching

How can I match the pattern `2.0.0.xxx` in lua?
I want a pattern which can match all such patterns.

Example:

If `a = 2.0.0.100 and b=2.0.0.200 c= 2.1.0.122 d=2.0.1.122`
only a and b should match the pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This pattern works:

```
"2%.0%.0%.%d%d%d"
```